# How to wrap cases together?

Tags: java, case, grouping

I am trying to group 3 cases together into 1 case.

How may I do so? Do I  use if, else if and else statements? If so, how?

```
    // Recourse
    case 2:

      // Turn Left Twice
      state++;
      if (state == 2) {
        c = 3;
      }
      return this.buildPhysicalAction(TurnLeftAction.class);

    // Move forwards
    case 3:
      c = 4;
      return this.buildPhysicalAction(MoveAction.class);

    // Turn right
    case 4:
      c = 1;
      return this.buildPhysicalAction(TurnRightAction.class);
    }
    return this.buildPerceiveAction();

  }
}
```

Comment: The three cases have different logic. What do you want to accomplish by grouping? What does "group 3 cases together" mean here?

Comment: Why you want group ? `2,3,4` have different business code

Comment: please elaborate your problem

Comment: Can you add the code for buildPhysicalAction method ?

Comment: I want to group cases 2, 3 and 4 to create one case - for generic code purposes

Answer (score 0):

Cases in java pass-through unless you include a `break`, so you can combine cases like this

```
case 2:
case 3:
case 4:
// Do what you want for 2, 3, and 4.
```

Comment: I want to combine the contents of cases 2, 3 and 4 into one case: 2

Comment: That's what this does.

Comment: You will need to add break in the last case to prevent condition leaking. So if either of 2 or 3 or 4 is true, 4 will be executed last

Comment: I want to execute case 2, 3 and then 4 all in one case

Answer (score 0):

When you add `return` statement the program will break out from the switch. Put `return` to the last case of your group in order to do what you want